# Check if div is hidden in AngularJS from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ng-show

I have a div that I am hiding/showing using angular in my HTML, but I want to know how to check if it is currently hidden or not in my controller.

Any solutions I have found so far are jQuery based using 'hasClass' to find ng-hide, but I don't want to use jQuery.

My div looks like this

```
<div class="item item-input" ng-show="showDetails"></div>

<button class="button button-block button-light leftTextButton" 
ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails; updateTimes()">
<i ng-class="{'icon icon ion-minus-round': showDetails, 
'icon icon ion-plus-round': !showDetails}"></i> End Time</button>
```

I thought from my controller I could just call if($scope.showDetails) and that would return true or false, but it is undefined.

How can I check if a div if hidden or showing from my controller? Thanks

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Your example works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/so6ouj9d/

Comment: hmm, something is definitely wrong with my scope so. Should "$scope.showDetails" be available in functions other than updateTimes? Or will it only be available to the functions you specify in ng-click?

Comment: It will be undefined until the first time you click your button because that is where you are setting it's value. You can predefine the value in your controller and then it won't be undefined. The `ng-show` initially works because `showDetails` equates to undefined therefore it isn't shown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are having a scoping issue. Passing it to the function that will check it is the best bet. Otherwise if it is in scope the controller should be able to access it.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.myBoolean = false;

      $scope.checkMyBooleanOnScope = function() {
        alert($scope.myBoolean);
      };

      $scope.checkMyOtherBooleanOnScope = function() {
        alert($scope.myOtherBoolean);
      };

      $scope.checkBooleanByPassingIt = function(bool) {
        alert(bool);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <p>myBoolean predefined in the controller:{{myBoolean}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myBoolean" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ng-click="checkMyBooleanOnScope()">checkMyOtherBooleanOnScope</button>
    <button ng-click="checkBooleanByPassingIt(myBoolean)">checkMyBooleanByPassingIt</button>

  </p>
  <p>myOtherBoolean defined on the page with ng-model:{{myOtherBoolean}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myOtherBoolean" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ng-click="checkMyOtherBooleanOnScope()">checkMyBooleanOnScope</button>
    <button ng-click="checkBooleanByPassingIt(myOtherBoolean)">checkMyOtherBooleanByPassingIt</button>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: You are right, something is wrong with my scope, but I can't see what. Adding function to the ng-click to check & change the scope variable seems to work. It seems cumbersome, but gets the job done. Thanks for your answer.